# Is there way to get the number of bytes transfered in Boost asio with coroutines

Tags: boost, boost-asio, boost-coroutine

I am using boost asio with coroutine to get some data from tcp socket.
In the exmaples shown in those document, the example looks like

```
http::async_read(socket, buffer, request, yield[ec]);
```

But how can I get number of bytes transferred in this case.

Without using coroutine we can bind a callback function.

```
void onReadDataComplete(boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
```

But it is not very clear how can I do the same thing with coroutine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read carefully this [link](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/spawn.html).

Your initiating function `async_read` can be called with `handler` or `yield`. Handler signature must be

```
void handler(boost::system::error_code ec, result_type result);
```

where `result` means how many bytes were read. When you call `async_read` with `yield` in place of `handler`, `async_read` returns `result_type` i.e. `size_t` - which means counter of read bytes. So you need only to check return value from `async_read`.

Comment: Thanks. When I saw handler, I regarded as the callback approach. Now I understand. Yeah, it is pretty straight forward.